# Is converting a date to a number more performant in queries?

Tags: sql, date, indexing

I want to improve performance on querying a subset based on date or datetime.

I wonder if a query would have better performance if I would create a second column next to the date-typed or datetime-typed column storing the date as a number.

An *int* (4 bytes long) should be sufficient and the format would be `YYYYMMDD`. I'm assuming indexing numbers is more efficient, but am not sure as DB technology probably optimises the types for indexing.

I understand `date/datetime-types` are stored as numbers opposed to a reference date. So the proposed alternative would avoid the overhead of mapping to a reference date.

Comment: A query doesn't need to `map to a reference date` its still just a number query.

Comment: BTW - please only add a single RDBMS as they are all different. (Which is why Gordon deleted them all).

Comment: (1) Use the built-in types.  Any slight advantage from indexing one type versus another is likely not to be noticeable in queries.  (2)  Questions about performance should have a SINGLE database tag, because capabilities differ among databases.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP or whatever thing your DMBS supports. It will almost certainly be using an integer or a series of integers internally (referenced to some epoch), but basically you don't need to and shouldn't care. Any performance difference will be microscopic compared to problems you might cause by issues in your design, and by computing a string from a date you risk making things worse or introducing errors.

If you're worried about performance, focus especially on appropriate indexing and use of clustering if necessary.